amsalpha bibliographystyle showing numerical labels instead labels constructed from the author name(s)
I have the following MWE
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

\begin{document}

This is a test, compare \cite{Fulton}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}

My biblio.bib is as follows
@book{Fulton,
    title        = {Representation Theory: A First Course},
    author       = {William Fulton and Joe Harris},
    year         = 2004,
    publisher      = {Springer Science + Business Media, Inc.},
    volume       = ,
}

This is what my PDF looks like:

How can I change the numerical labels to labels constructed from the author name(s)?

Does it work if you put \bibliographystyle{... on the line right before \bibliography{... in your document? That's usually how it is done.

Thanks for your consideration @cfr. The answer of David solved the issue.

In fact, I think your suggestion was also part of the solution as I followed your advise prior to removing the amsref and removing amsref didn't seem to solve it entirely, it was a combination of both (it seems).

You are using amsrefs so it explicitly documents that any \bibliographystyle command is ignored, see texdoc amsrefs section 2.3.
In most cases you do not want to load amsrefs package but it depends on your publication requirements.

Thank you David, that was indeed the issue! I appreciate your help!
